# how to handle public and private jsp pages/servlet under login with a Filter

Tags: java, jsp

i've been studying for a while Java and jsp.
Im developing a little application to test my knowledge. In my application i have some public pages and some pages that need to log in.
For every jsp page I have a servlet that handles it.

I created a filter to check if a user is logged in by checking if a session exist.

My question is: how should i handle the jsp pages/servlet? Should i put the public jsp pages/servlet in one folder and the 'private' jsp pages/servlet in another and tell the filter to check just the jsp pages/servlet under the 'private' folder?
Or should i tell the filter to check every jsp pages/servlet and tell it as well what jsp pages/servlet are not private so it knows that it doesn't need to redirect users to the login page?

Comment: You want to filter every request for security.  You should have one JSP folder.  Resources like images/CSS can be skipped in the filter.

Comment: put the jsp under the WEB-INF folder so that they are not directly accessible.  Have a `priv` and a `pub` servlet tree and a filter to check for login or not

Comment: Thanks both of you. The solutions of @ScaryWombat seems the best, ill try to aplly it. Ill disturb you again if i need more help. :)

Comment: when you say to create a priv servlet tree, u mean that i have to set the 'url' to reach a servlet this way: @WebServlet({ "/priv/addHuman".....?